# Klout installation not auto populating std fields in Salesforce for Social Media App

Tags: appexchange, salesforce2salesforce, app, connected-apps

[Salesforce for Twitter and Facebook](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HpEQEA0) (v4.6), includes a Klout score and Klout number field.

If I manually entered Klout number in as 59 the app will then auto populate the Klout score. Should this be automated and live updating if the contacts Klout score changes? Has anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried sending an email to the contact address on the Details tab of their AppExchange page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a temporary workaround I created an app for last years Dreamforce to display a klout score as formula image: http://www.radnip.com/social-influence-score-as-an-image-using-klout/